# Why are my searches so slow on my host?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me begin at saying that I have an excel spreedsheet with all my data in called catelogue. It has 27 fields. Many of these fields can be split into a separate table as the data is been repeated. I import this table into mysql as a csv and when I was testing with wamp it worked fine. There are 2 tables in mysql one been this one i have explained and then another one with tracklisting. This has many records witch link to the catelogue table. I had my SQL looking like this to search

```
SELECT `ARTIST` , `TITLE` , `CAT NO.` , `FORMAT` , `DEPARTMENT` , 
 `SELL`,`IMAGE PATH`,`RELEASEDATE` 
FROM catelogue
WHERE `DEPARTMENT` LIKE 'MUSIC'
AND ( `ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `CAT NO. IN
(SELECT * FROM tracklisting
WHERE `ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `TRACKTITLE`LIKE '%$theValue%' )
    ORDER BY `RELEASEDATE` DESC
```

Yes this worked perfectly for how I wanted it to work but unfortunataly it didn't work at all on my hosts server.

So I moved on to to this with help from a couple guys here on stack overflow

```
SELECT  *
FROM    catelogue c
    LEFT JOIN   tracklisting t
        ON  t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.` = c.`CAT NO.`
WHERE   `DEPARTMENT` = 'MUSIC'
        AND ((  c.'ARTIST' LIKE '%$theValue%' OR c.'TITLE' LIKE '%$theValue%')
                OR
                (t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%'))
ORDER BY    `RELEASEDATE` DESC
```

Now this did work in a fashion, but every item that had a tracklisting was returned how ever many tracks there were for that album. So 15 tracks for Lady Gaga and 15 repeats. Now nothing against the guys that help me, I'm very apprieciative of the help, this was faster than my original but it still took sometime. It did load the page but was not as fast as I wanted.

I have moved to this just so my search is quick enough but it doesn't search my tracklistings.

```
SELECT `ARTIST` , `TITLE` , `CAT NO.` , `FORMAT` , `DEPARTMENT` , `SELL`,`IMAGE PATH`,`RELEASEDATE` 
FROM catelogue
WHERE `DEPARTMENT` LIKE 'MUSIC'
AND ( `ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR `TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%' )
    ORDER BY `RELEASEDATE` DESC"
```

So my Question is, How do I get a SQL statement that will search my catelogue and my tracklisting without taking FOREVER to do so or returning duplicates.

Would 3 separate querys work faster if the first 2 searched and returned the CAT NO. into an array and then a third one with a foreach statement in php?

All my DB's are saved as InnoDB.

Thanks

**Apologies For the slow response**

**So an Update**

I ran a bit of a test myself. Duno how valid it may be but With my original query with the IN statement it takes on between 0.3 and 0.4 seconds on my local host with wamp.

The joins seem to take roughly the same time. Distinct was also the same. The first distinct took over a second but after that it ran at .3 or .4 times

My last simple query with no joins or In's that just searches one table takes about 0.1 sec.

Now I'm not to clued up on this but this seems pretty fast.

The only query that works on hosts server is the basic one. Insert also works fine but it's also simple.

So my New question.

Is my ISP been stupid and not allowing any joins or In's in my SQL and just freezing up to tell you what you are doing can't be done?

Comment: you could have  a table with myisam and use full text searches

Comment: @yes123: I don't think that would work. All Mark's conditions are `LIKE '%___%'`. The wildcards at the beginning of of the term render fulltext indexes useless.

Comment: @Ben: full text has BOOLEAN SEARCH taht can replicate that, and for sure it could be faster

Comment: @yes123: To my knowledge running a BOOLEAN search has no affect on this. The documentation on fulltext boolean searches says that wildcard characters can ONLY be appended to the search term... which makes sense, as fulltext indexes work BECAUSE they are filed according to the string letter order: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html ... If you have an example of a fulltext search where the initial character(s) are wildcard, I'd love to know about it, but it would seem to run counter to the principle of FULLTEXT optimization

Comment: Run a test. I believe fulltext searches will be still faster than a LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Try this to eliminate the duplicates. Because less data is being returned, you may find it faster too:

```
SELECT distinct c.*
FROM catelogue c
LEFT JOIN tracklisting t ON  t.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.` = c.`CAT NO.`
WHERE `DEPARTMENT` = 'MUSIC'
    AND ((c.'ARTIST' LIKE '%$theValue%' OR c.'TITLE' LIKE '%$theValue%')
        OR
        (t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%'))
ORDER BY `RELEASEDATE` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The big issue at play here is that MySQL cannot use any index to speed up a queries beginning with a wildcard. Neither can any other database servers. It requires a full table table scan to lookup every possible result. Add an order statement and you force to scan everything with no early exit condition.

You can either use MySQL full text search, which is easy enough as it is always available, or use an external full text search utility, such as Sphinx, ElasticSearch, Solr, or something else. There are many alternatives.

Otherwise, you can also do the job yourself by having a words table and indexing your content into those. However, I would not recommend this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
SELECT  *
FROM    catelogue c   
WHERE   c.`DEPARTMENT` = 'MUSIC'
    AND ((  c.'ARTIST' LIKE '%$theValue%' OR c.'TITLE' LIKE '%$theValue%')
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting t
WHERE 
     (t.`ARTIST` LIKE '%$theValue%' OR t.`TRACK TITLE` LIKE '%$theValue%'))
```

in two temporary tables, then LEFT JOIN, do DISTINCT and ORDER BY on these two tempoprary tables.